# How do I add extra information to the web2py error ticket?

Tags: web2py

I would like to make the referrer visible in error tickets, so I can see where an erroneous link comes from. How do I do that?

I'm thinking of doing something like request['referer'] = request['wsgi']['environ']['HTTP_REFERER'], so that it shows up in the request. Where do I hook that in, so it gets added whenever an error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Errors and ticket generation are handled in [/gluon/restricted.py](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/restricted.py). In particular, the request, response, and session details are added near the end of the [snapshot function](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/restricted.py#L243).

If you want to do some custom ticket handling without altering the framework code, look at [this](http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/75) for some ideas.

If you just need to do some temporary debugging of a particular function, you could do a `try...except` within the function, and upon exception, output the request object using the BEAUTIFY helper. Something like this:

```
def your_function():
    try:
        # YOUR FUNCTION CODE
    except:
        response.view = 'generic.html'
        return dict(req=BEAUTIFY(request))
```

The above will display every item within the request object, including the referrer.

If you have more questions or would like to recommend changes to the error ticket functionality, I recommend asking on the [web2py mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/web2py).

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary solution, you can add that line at around line 375 in gluon/main.py
We will discuss on web2py-developers for a more general solution. feel free to join us.